# How to describe this nullspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is $4\times 4$ and invertible matrix, describe the nullspace of the $4\times 8$ matrix $B=[A\,A]$.

The solution is: The nullspace of $B=[A\,A]$ contains all vectors x=
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    y \\
    -y
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

for y in $R^4$.

But I doubt this solution because it seems that it doesn't use invertible condition.

My idea is that since A is invertible, then r(A)=4, then n-r(B)=8-4=4. So the nullspace of B has 4 free variables.

Answer (score 1):

As the solution says, the null space *contains* all such vectors, as you can see by a simple calculation.

It also *only* contains those vectors. This follows from the rank-nullity theorem once you know the rank of $B$. What is it? Why?

Comment: A is invertible matrix. Does the solution use this condition?

Comment: @YaoZhao Yes. To be slightly more explicit, you have a four dimensional subspace of the nullspace of $B$. You ultimately need to use the invertibility of $A$ to conclude that this subspace is actually the whole nullspace of $B$.

Comment: I don't agree. N(B) is a subspace of 8 dimension.

Comment: @YaoZhao No, $N(B)$ is a subspace of an 8 dimensional space, but it is itself a 4 dimensional space.